# Lines from vertices through centroid of a triangle bisect opposite sides.

Tags: triangles, centroid

It is well known that the lines from the vertices through the centroid of a general triangle bisect the sides opposite to each vertex. Is there a simple geometrical proof for this? I've managed to solve it using vector-algebra, but it's not nice to say the least. Below is a short Maple-Code for the proof: I started with the line starting at vertex $A$ (with angle $a$) that bisects $CB$ and similarly the line starting at vertex $B$ (with angle $b$) that bisects $AC$. Those 2 lines intersect at some point that turns out to be the centroid. Now I construct a third line that starts at vertex $C$ and goes through that intersection/centroid and I show that (in the coordinate-system) at $y=0$ this line will have x-coordinate $AB/2$ which is the midpoint of the side AB.

The equations that I use below read $$t\begin{pmatrix} AB-\frac{CB}{2}\cos b \\ \frac{CB}{2} \sin b \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{CA}{2} \cos a \\ \frac{CA}{2} \sin a \end{pmatrix} - s\left[\begin{pmatrix} \frac{CA}{2}\cos a \\ \frac{CA}{2} \sin a \end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} AB \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\right]$$
where the LHS is the line from the vertex $A$ ($t=0$) at the origin to the midpoint of side $CB$ ($t=1$) and the RHS is the line from the midpoint of $CA$ ($s=0$) to the vertex $B$ ($s=1$) at $x=AB$.

```
restart;
eqs := [t*(AB - cos(b)*CB/2) = cos(a)*CA/2 - s*(cos(a)*CA/2 - AB), t*sin(b)*CB/2 = sin(a)*CA/2 - s*sin(a)*CA/2];
sol := solve(eqs, [t, s]);
simplify~(eval(eqs, sol[1]));
coords := [lhs(%[1]), lhs(%[2])];
coords2 := [(1 - t)*cos(a)*CA + t*coords[1], (1 - t)*sin(a)*CA + t*coords[2]];
solve(coords2[2], t);
simplify~(eval(coords2, t = %));
simplify~(eval(%, cos(b) = (AB - cos(a)*CA)/CB));
simplify~(eval(%, sin(b) = sin(a)*CA/CB));
```

Comment: I usually _define_ the centroid to be the intersection of the medians (lines that connect a vertex and the midpoint of its opposite side).

Comment: Well. Two lines intersect at 1 point, but it is not a-priori clear that the third median goes through that same intersection point, or?

Answer (score 1):

Let ABC be a triangle , with vertices $A(0,0) ,B(x_1,y_1)$ and $C(x_2 , y_2)$.

Therefore , coordinates of centroid G are $G({x_1 + x_2 \over 3 }) , ({{ y_1 + y_2} \over 3})$.

Let the line through A and G cut BC at D(x,y), where D divides BC in the ratio $k:1$.

Therefore $$(x,y)=\left ({k x_2 + x_1 \over k+1 } \right)  ,\left( {k y_2 + y_1 \over k+1 }\right)$$

Now slope(AG) = slope(GD) .

Therefore , $${{{ky_2 + y_1 \over k+1} - {y_1 + y_2 \over 3}} \over {{kx_2 + x_1 \over k+1} - {x_1 + x_2 \over 3}}} = {{y_1 + y_2 \over x_1 + x_2 }}$$

Which on solving gives you k=1.

Therefore , AG divides BC in the ratio 1:1 , hence ,D is the mid point of B and C .

Comment: That's neat, but I'll leave it open, since I'd love to see other versions.

Answer (score 0):

The natural setting for this problem is [affine space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space). Lines are
preserved under an affine transformation and the midpoint
of a line segment is also preserved. Any triangle is an
affine transform of an equilateral triangle for which the

> lines from the vertices through the centroid of a general triangle bisect the sides opposite to each vertex

is clearly true. Since it is true for the special case of
equilateral triangles, and this property is preserved by
affine transformations, it is true in general.

Comment: Any source , or book you would recommend through which I can know more about this subject "affine geometry" and other related ones ? Because this seems very interesting

Comment: @Sukhoi234 One good book is Coxeter, _Introduction to Geometry_.